# What is ADR in Counter Strike?

Tags: terminology, counter-strike-global-offensive

In the stats of the spectating screen of CSGO, I've found myself wondering what is the ADR column.

It looks like some kind of ratio on 1000, but have no idea what it calculates.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**ADR** stands for **Average Damage per Round**

As K/D ratio is statistical representation used to measure how good you are in free for all game mods,the ADR is used to represent how useful you are in the team games.

Also Overkill damage is not counted in ADR.

---

In case you wonder HS% is "Head Shot percentage" and OBJ is number of objective you have done.

Comment: Thanks! And yes I figured that out. Also, 3k, 4k and 5k stand for 3, 4 and 5 kills in a round